# Its possible to get a param name in a method where the param is the result of a function

Tags: java, reflection

When you pass to a function other functions as params there is a way to get the param functions names ?

I tried with reflection but looks like the information do not appears.

```java
public static String LeftFunction(String left) {
  ... Do stuff
  return left;
}

public static String RightFunction(String right) {
  ... Do stuff
  return right;
}
```

Now if I use a main function like

```java
findRoute(LeftFunction("street 1"), LeftFunction("street 2"), RightFunction("Street 3"));
```

Is there a way where `findRoute` function can know if the param 1, 2, 3 .. is called from function left, right, up ....

Comment: No. Parameter names are not preserved in the bytecode. The process of evaluation is irrelevant.

Comment: I want to calculate something based on the param positions, so I want to know if is to the left, to the right of the given params

Comment: Your problem seems like traversing a tree. @nonyck

Comment: If so then visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: And even if it was possible it wouldn't tell you about the way it was evaluated. Classic XY problem. Your method should not behave differently dpending on how it was called. This is called 'state orientation', and it was discarded in the 1960s.

Comment: Do you want `findRoute` be aware of the names of passed arguments such as `Street 1`, `Street 2`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to get the names of a function's parameter names at runtime.   The reflection API doesn't expose the names.

Indeed, if I am reading your code correctly, you are not passing the functions at all:

```
findRoute(LeftFunction("street 1"), 
          LeftFunction("street 2"), 
          RightFunction("Street 3"));
```

This is *evaluating* the functions and passing the *results* to the `findRoute` method.  In other words, `findRoute` doesn't even know what functions were called, let alone anything about the names of their parameters.

Now it would be possible to write some convoluted code that wrapped functions and their names and then "curried" them with a particular argument like you appear to be trying to doing.  But there are probably better ways ... of doing whatever it is that you are *actually* trying to do here.